# Saving Multiple Circles to Bitmap android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-button

I need to save a number of formatted circles to a Bitmap whenever a button is pushed, and then draw those circles to the canvas. I was looking around, but had a great deal of trouble finding resources on how to save a shape I had created that was not an already created resource file. Any advice on how to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: In what format is the 'shape' information store? Do you need to save the bitmap to disk?

Comment: I do not need to save the bitmap to the disk, but I do need to store whatever circles I create while the application is running. It does not matter if all the information is lost once the application is closed.

Comment: So you are painting over a view, say with you finger, and you want to save what you have painted to a bitnap. Is it correct?

Comment: That's a unique way to put it, but I'd say that's the gist of it.

Comment: Ok I gave my answer, let me know if it is what you really wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you are in your custom view, but it should work also with a OnTouchListener in any view.

- Create a mutable bitmap with Bitmap.createBitmap() with the same width and height of your view
- use your logic for getting information of the circles, for example you can use onTouchEvent() to get the coordinates of you finger(s)
- with this information you can use Bitmap.setPixel() to save it to the bitmap
- optional, onDraw() you can draw your bitmap with Canvas.drawBitmap()

In case you need to draw shapes to the bitmap you can create a new Canvas(bitmap) and draw on this canvas: the pixels will be set on the bitmap.

Comment: Ah, this is essentially what I had in mind. When the coordinate information is saved to the bitmap, is any other information saved as well such as the color of the circle I drew?

Comment: Both setPixel() and drawing into a canvas backed up by a bitmap save the color information.

Comment: I forgot, for the canvas approach you need to set the color in the paint you pass in in the draw*() calls